# Magento2: Minicart issue on Custom layout

Tags: magento2, layout, category, mini-cart

I am using a custom layout for the category page.

Here is my code:

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/page_layout/equipment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="equipmentbase"/>   
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/page_layout/equipmentbase.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                    <container name="equipment.main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="equipment check main"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

I have created a custom layout using the above code. But in this layout minicart is not rendering.
If I use 1column then it is working fine.

Please tell me what I missing here. Or Correction.